Why does TypeScript give a "possibly undefined" error when using a conditional and `Array.map`?
Consider this minimal example:
const an_array: Array<number> = new Array(100).fill(3.5);     // init some array
let a: [number, number, number] | undefined;                  // and declare a possibly undefined 3-vector
const b = a !== undefined ? an_array.map(x => x + a[2]) : 0;

On line 3, TS complains that 'a' is possibly undefined. As far as I can see, it must be defined in a single-threaded environment, as the ternary operator eliminates the possibility that it is undefined. (The same occurs if the ternary is replaced with an if/else statement.)
I think that the Array.map callback must be the culprit somehow, because if the third line is instead
const b = a !== undefined ? a[2] : 0;

then there are no complaints. Is TS possibly worried that the callback in map could assign to a such that it becomes undefined? If so, surely it's not hard for the compiler to see that this cannot happen.

This is ms/TS#9998. See linked q/a above.

@jcalz I see, thanks. This makes a lot of sense.
